# Reading 2 byte utf8 binary data

Tags: node.js, buffer, binaryfiles, endianness

I have binary files that contain utf8 strings for example.

> 4F 00 4B 00

I'm trying to read this data and write it out to a text file but when I do the following:

```
data.toString('utf8');
```

I get an output of:

> O K

Take note of the two spaces being interpreted from the `00`. Is there any way to specify I'm using 2 byte little endian characters? I imagine if this didn't contain ascii characters this would actually break and produce garbage data instead of extra spaces.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem likely is when you're reading, not writing the string. The string you shared is not UTF-8, it's UTF-16. So what I'm thinking you want is to *read* the string as UTF-16 and write it as UTF-8.

Specifically this is UTF-16LE.

Comment: Thanks, I just realized how stupid my question was, `utf8` implies 8 bit characters, where I clearly have 16 bit characters.